# Where can I find the source code of sculpt mode?

Tags: python

Im developing a new behaviour for sculpt mode, but I couldn't find the source code.

How can I view and/or edit the source code?

Comment: Try looking through the git repository at developer.blender.org. Also the python tag is wrong here, sculpt mode is C code. If you are interested in getting involved in blender development this is not the right place, get in contact with the dev team via the #blendercoders IRC channel or the mailing list.

Comment: @Sazerac thank u for the answer, I was hoping that this part wasn't in C because I don't have idea of C, time to start I suppose, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sculpt mode isn't developed in Python, it's in C. It can be found that in `\source\blender\editors\sculpt_paint`.